# Word for expressing something uncertain with certainty

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for when someone says something confidently even though it is uncertain ?

Comment: ***Assertifiction***.

Comment: @DanBron - I'm *almost* sure you're deliberately saying something confidently even though you don't actually know...

Comment: @Michael - Please add an example sentence, as required for [tag:single-word-requests]. This is so we know whether you're looking for a verb, a noun, an adjective, etc. I'm recommending to close the question until this info is provided, to stop answers which aren't providing the sort of word you're looking for.

Comment: @AndyT Sir, that is libel! And under US Constitutional law, as determined in Sup. Ct. R. 24(f) recorded at 78 Fed. Reg. 15410 (March 11, 2013)  (to be codified at 45 C.F.R. pts. 153, 155,156, 157, & 158), you owe me an apology and a sandwich. Bologna, please.

Comment: Is "Assertifiction" a word? It doesn't show up when I checked a dictionary.

Comment: I think the posting of assertification might have been an assertification. :)

Answer (score 1):

> **Assertion**
>   [uh-sur-shuh n]
>   /noun
>
> 1. a positive statement or declaration, often without support or reason:
>      a mere assertion; an unwarranted assertion.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/assertion)

Answer (score 0):

**Bluff.** To try to deceive someone as to one's abilities or intentions.
Which is just the definition off of google.

If you put it into a context you could also use pretend, lie, false bravado, a ruse, feigned confidence or mislead could all work. It'd depend on the wording of the rest of the sentence.

"Raise." He bluffed, pushing more poker chips into the pot - his hand was a rather poor one.

"Raise." He said, smirking with feigned confidence at the other players -his hand was a rather poor one.

He's 'bluffing' the other players. Trying to imply he has good cards, has *confidence* that he will win even though it is *uncertain*.

Comment: DV - Bluff refers to taking a false concept and presenting it as true. This is not the same as to taking an uncertain concept and presenting it as fact.

Comment: Yes usually. Assertion is probably the better answer in this question, but I believe it's at least partly a matter of context. I definitely see what you're saying though - bluffing is more lying outright then being unsure.

Comment: I agree that it's close, but wouldn't a bluffer be certain of both the fact and the bluff. Is there uncertainty involved with the actor?

Comment: Also, Welcome to ELU.SE!

Comment: Could be. I tend to thin k of bluffing in the context of gambling, and there's always at least some uncertainty there.